# Sotring background image URL in a cookie using jQuery

Tags: jquery

I am using jQuery to extract the URL of a background image and then store this in a cookie (to be used elsewhere on the site):

```
var pageImage = jQuery('#image > div').css("background-image");
```

This value is not being passed to the cookie, and using console.log(pageImage) I can see that the value being stored is:

```
url("https://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg")
```

I need to store just the URL string in the cookie i.e:

```
https://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg
```

Any help as to how to remove `url("` and `")` using jQuery (in the cleanest way possible)?

Comment: pageImage.replace('url("', '').replace('")', '');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can read more about cookies here https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

```js
var str = `url("https://www.example.com/images/image1.jpg")`;
var res_url = str.substring(5,str.length-2);
console.log(res_url);
// and then
// document.cookie = res_url;
```

But generally using cookie and specially for such a task is not recommended.
try using Web Storage instead :

[HTML web storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Storage_API) provides two objects for storing data on the client:

- window.localStorage - stores data with no expiration date
- window.sessionStorage - stores data for one session (data is lost
  when the browser tab is closed)

  ```
  // Store
  localStorage.setItem("desire-background", "url-of-background-image");
  // Retrieve
  document.getElementById("result")
      .style.backgroundImage = localStorage.getItem("desire-background");
  ```